# Why I am not getting answers to my questions?

Tags: discussion, comments

I am observing this from few days. I am not getting responses for whatever questions I asked.

Initially, whenever I asked question, whether it is easy or difficult, I got answers/comments within 1-2 minutes.

Now, I am not getting any response, neither answer, nor even comment for the 4-5 questions which I posted recently.

What is the reason behind this? I also tried adding a bounty on my questions, but all in vain...

Comment: Can you add links to the questions in question. It's much easier to help you when we can see what you are talking about.

Comment: @ChrisF http://stackoverflow.com/users/1152004/microsoft-dn?tab=questions&sort=newest Some of the newest ones do not have answers.

Comment: Don't hesitate to update your question to improve it. It will make them more attractive, and will also push them to the top of SO.

Answer (score 3):

I'd say it's the tags you're using.  With the exception of "C#", your tags all seem to be very specific.  For example, you've got some questions tagged "oracle10g".  Not many people will subscribe to this.  If you used the "sql" tag instead, you'd get a much higher readership.  Similarly "extjs2", "sql-update", "requirements".  These tags are not helping you.

Answer (score 2):

Some of your [newest questions](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1152004/microsoft-dn?tab=questions&sort=newest) don't have answers right now, but they have very few views: 12, 19, 25. So maybe one factor is that **nobody sees them**.

Out of the 18 questions you have asked this year so far, only 4 are actually unanswered, which makes a 22% ratio - I don't think that is so bad. So all I can say is **keep on trying**, especially try to get more views, attracting users to your unanswered questions.